# Flickity carousel not sizing slides width correctly in Firefox

Tags: html, firefox, image-gallery, flickity

I try to use [flickity](http://flickity.metafizzy.co/) to have a good looking lazy loading image carousel. It works great on chrome and safari but the slide doesn't size correctly to the image in firefox.

Please try the following link with firefox and another browser to get the idea: [imagescroll](http://jdenuijl.com/test/imagescroll.php)

Does anyone knows how to fix the issue with firefox without losing the ability to have variable slide widths? Thank you very much!

```
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/flickity@2.0/dist/flickity.css" media="screen">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=0">        
<style>
  * {box-sizing: border-box;}

  body { margin: 0; padding: 0;}

  .imgc {
         background-repeat: no-repeat;
         background-size: cover;
         height: 100%;
        }
  .carousel img {
         display: block;
         height: 100%;
         opacity: 0;
         transition: opacity 0.7s;
        }
.carousel img.flickity-lazyloaded {
         opacity: 1;
        }

</style>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/flickity@2.0/dist/flickity.pkgd.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<!-- Flickity HTML init -->
<div class="carousel" data-flickity='{ "imagesLoaded": true, "percentPosition": false, "wrapAround":true,"draggable": true, "pageDots": false, "prevNextButtons": false,"setGallerySize": false,"lazyLoad":true,"lazyLoad": 1}'>
  <div class="imgc" style="background-image: url('static/room/image1_small.jpg')">
    <img src="static/room/image1_small.jpg" data-flickity-lazyload="static/room/comp/image1.jpg" alt="orange tree" />
  </div>
  <div class="imgc" style="background-image: url('static/room/image2_small.jpg')">
    <img src="static/room/image2_small.jpg" data-flickity-lazyload="static/room/comp/image2.jpg" alt="submerged" />
  </div>
  <div class="imgc" style="background-image: url('static/room/image3_small.jpg')">
    <img src="static/room/image3_small.jpg" data-flickity-lazyload="static/room/comp/image3.jpg" alt="look-out" />
  </div>
  <div class="imgc" style="background-image: url('static/room/image4_small.jpg')">
    <img src="static/room/image4_small.jpg" data-flickity-lazyload="static/room/comp/image4.jpg" alt="One World Trade" />
  </div>
  <div class="imgc" style="background-image: url('static/room/image5_small.jpg')">
    <img src="static/room/image5_small.jpg" data-flickity-lazyload="static/room/comp/image5.jpg" alt="drizzle" />
  </div>
  <div class="imgc" style="background-image: url('static/room/image6_small.jpg')">
    <img src="static/room/image6_small.jpg" data-flickity-lazyload="static/room/comp/image6.jpg" alt="cat nose" />
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```